# GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent crashes when child process is cmd

Tags: c++, windows, process, console, signals

I'm trying to wrap basic windows process functionalities in a Process Class.
I want the processes to run in the same process group and same console of the parent, and I want to kill them gently when I call Process::Kill();

Reading from various sources I've ended up with this code, which first checks if the process is a GUI, if so sends a WM_CLOSE (the EnumChildWindowsHandler does it), if not, and the process has a console, sends a CTRL_C event. It works, but when the child Process is the "cmd.exe" the procedure crashes on the GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent function and the debugger says an access violation on write happened.

What's the point? What didn't I understand in my readings?

```
bool Process::Kill( ) {  
  // Here I check if the process is a GUI app  
  if (!EnumThreadWindows(mChildInfo->dwThreadId, EnumChildWindowsHandler,  mChildInfo->dwProcessId)) {
    if (WaitForSingleObject(mChildInfo->hProcess, 2000) == WAIT_TIMEOUT) {
      { TerminateProcess(mChildInfo->hProcess, 0); }  }

  //If not, test if it's a CUI then send CTRL_C
  else { 
    int minPid = 10;
    int els;
    unsigned long *pids = new unsigned long(minPid);
    els =  GetConsoleProcessList( pids, minPid );
    if (els > minPid) {
      free (pids);
      pids = new unsigned long(els);
      els = GetConsoleProcessList(pids, els);
    }

    if (find(pids, pids+els, mChildInfo->dwProcessId)) {
      cout << "Sending CTRL_C_EVENT.." << endl;

      SetConsoleCtrlHandler(NULL, TRUE);
      GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent(CTRL_C_EVENT, 0);
      if (WaitForSingleObject(mChildInfo->hProcess, 2000) == WAIT_TIMEOUT) { TerminateProcess(mChildInfo->hProcess, 0); }
      SetConsoleCtrlHandler(NULL, FALSE);  

      CloseHandle(mChildInfo->hProcess);
      CloseHandle(mChildInfo->hThread);
    } 
    return true;   
  }
```

EDIT: I've found the ReactOS cmd.exe source code which is gold for this sort of thing.  I'll post updates from what I eventually learn.
Url: http://doxygen.reactos.org/db/d4f/base_2shell_2cmd_2cmd_8c_source.html

Comment: I can't reproduce the error, but the cmd.exe control handler `cmd!Handler` generally ignores `CTRL+C` and `CTRL+BREAK` except when running a batch file. In the latter case it displays the prompt `"Terminate batch job (Y/N)?"`. In your case is cmd running with an interactive command prompt, a single `/c` command, or executing a batch file? BTW, process groups (i.e. `CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP`) have `CTRL+C` disabled unless it gets manually enabled, so it would be more reliable to use `CTRL_BREAK_EVENT`. But you'll need to set an actual handler that ignores `CTRL+BREAK` in your own process.

Comment: If you do use `CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP` to create the child process, you should generate the event for just the child's PID, which doubles as the process group ID. That way only the child process, along with any console processes that it creates, will see the event. Generating the event for group 0 will send it to even your own parent process if it's attached to the same console. That could have unintended consequences.

Comment: The child process is just an instance of "cmd.exe" running in the parent Console, no new group is created (since groups prevent sending CTRL_C). Maybe i should look at the GenerateConsoleInput.
OR
I could just run every single program in a new console redirecting the streams to my console and then sending a CTRL_C to a detached process.
Btw, i didn't find a good explanation about differences in CTRL_C and CTRL_BREAK, do the last also terminate gently an application?

Comment: A process has a default control event handler, `kernel32!DefaultHandler`, that calls `ExitProcess`. In that case DLL entry points will be called with `DLL_PROCESS_DETACH`, so for examlple, CRT `atexit` functions will be called. That said, a process can chain multiple event handlers and won't necessarily chain to the default handler. For example, the CRT installs a handler for raising `SIGINT` and `SIGBREAK` for `CTRL+C` and `CTRL+BREAK` events.

Answer (score 1):

The cmd source code explains well how to do correctly, BTW I just use the CTRL_BREAK and works like a charm. In the create process I pass CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP and I set the SW_SHOWDEFAULT for the showWindow mode, and then I kill processes this way:

```
//Determine if lParam has for main window the hWnd, and send WM_CLOSE
int CALLBACK EnumChildWindowsHandler(HWND hWnd, LPARAM lParam) 
{ 
  //WORD type
  unsigned long pid = 0;
  GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnd, &pid);

  if (pid == (unsigned long) lParam) {
    cout << "HANDLEWIN: "  << hWnd <<  " Bwehe" << endl;
    cout << "PID: " << pid << endl;

    if (!GetParent(hWnd)) PostMessageA(hWnd, WM_CLOSE, 0, 0);
    return 0;
  }
  return 1; 
}

bool Process::KillGently( ) {
  if (EnumThreadWindows(mProcInfo->dwThreadId, EnumChildWindowsHandler,  mProcInfo->dwProcessId)) {
     if (!GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent(CTRL_BREAK_EVENT, mProcInfo->dwProcessId))
      cerr << "Error while sending CTRL_BREAK_EVENT: " << GetLastError() << endl;
  }
```

Also, if we want to act in a cmd like way while handling signals, we can register a sighandler like this (we still nedd the WriteConsoleInput):

```
BOOL signal_handler(DWORD signum) {

  INPUT_RECORD iRecord;

  if (signum != CTRL_C_EVENT && signum != CTRL_BREAK_EVENT ) return FALSE;

  if(!TryEnterCriticalSection(&mChildRunningLock)) {
     GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent(CTRL_BREAK_EVENT, mChild.mProcInfo->dwProcessId);
     mIsBreakHandled = true;
     return TRUE;
  }
  else  LeaveCriticalSection(&mChildRunningLock);

  iRecord.EventType = KEY_EVENT;
  iRecord.Event.KeyEvent.bKeyDown = TRUE;
  iRecord.Event.KeyEvent.wRepeatCount = TRUE;
  iRecord.Event.KeyEvent.wVirtualKeyCode = _T('C');
  iRecord.Event.KeyEvent.wVirtualScanCode = _T('C') - 35;
  iRecord.Event.KeyEvent.uChar.AsciiChar = _T('C');
  iRecord.Event.KeyEvent.uChar.UnicodeChar = _T('C');
  iRecord.Event.KeyEvent.dwControlKeyState = RIGHT_CTRL_PRESSED;

  WriteConsoleInputA(GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE), &iRecord, 1, 0);
  mIsBreakHandled = true;
  return TRUE;
}
```

The main thread enters the critical section while waiting for the termination for the process just started.

BTW I still don't know why my application was crashing with the previous code.